# How does one prove that a particular bacterium causes a disease if we've found it in the blood of all infected people?

Tags: pathology

Let's say we have a new disease and are trying to identify the cause. We isolate, though culture, a new microbe from the blood of all infected people. Is it enough to say that it isn't present in healthy people, but in all our infected people, to come to the conclusion that this microbe is the cause of the disease? Why, or why not?

I feel intuitively that using Koch's way of introducing these microbes into a healthy individual to see if they cause the same disease, is a fool-proof way of proving that it causes this disease.

However, some of my students have said that they would like to test the blood of healthy individuals to see if they can find that microbe in it. If not, then the microbe can be said to cause that disease. This seems all right too, except that it only proves correlation, not causation. Does it suffice?

Comment: As you're new to this site, you might not be aware that some research is required on your part in order not to get a close vote or a down vote. Providing evidence of a search (not typing that you've searched but found nothing) and editing what you've found into your question is much more likely to get you an answer.

Comment: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0361/58a9ea43125e9802bb5e2b5db2118f51d81a.pdf